# AngularJS directive DOM manipulation not executing link()

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, dom-manipulation

Trying to do some DOM manipulation, but `link()` is never called so nothing happens:

**app.js**

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['directives', ...]);
var directives = angular.module('directives', []);
...
```

**directives.js**

```
directives.directive('doIt', ['$window', function($window) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            console.log('Inside link()');
            // Do stuff with $window
        }
    };
]});
```

**HTML**

```
<html ng-app="app">
    <body>
        <div ng-view>
            <div do-it>
                // ....
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your square bracket is incorrect

```
directives.directive('doIt', ['$window', function($window) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            console.log('Inside link()');
            // Do stuff with $window
        }
    };

    }]);//Check this part. The square bracket was on the wrong side of }
```

Move it like like I have it above

You also have some extra periods in your module decleration

`var app = angular.module('app', ['directives']);` //remove the extra ....'s

Comment: Ah ha, I found out the problem... I forgot to include `directives.js` in my `index.html`. D'oh!

Answer (score 1):

is this plnkr help?[plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/Dc0kRdLM4dVKGqoqmd1v?p=preview)

```
 angular.module('app', [])
// .controller('Controller', ['$scope', function($scope) {
//   $scope.customer = {
//     name: 'Naomi',
//     address: '1600 Amphitheatre'
//   };
// }])
.directive('doIt', ['$window', function($window) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
        console.log('Inside link()');
        // Do stuff with $window
    }
  };
}]);
```